# htaccess remove .php on multiple system file extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess. This works ok for system generate urls on section.php. But when i add extra lines for article.php, product.php, page.php, contact.php its not working. Any ideas on adding multiple mod rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xampleco.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.xample.co.uk/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# Redirect .php URLs to rewritten URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Rewrite URLs for processing by router (section.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ section.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# These are working
Redirect 301 /files/example.pdf http://www.example.co.uk
Redirect 301 /section.php/11/1/life-drawing http://www.example.co.uk

# This is working, but leaves a trail of the url onto the redirect, ok but would be nice to be    cleaner
Redirect 301 /section/116/1/drawings http://www.example.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` ones and keep redirect rules before internal ones.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.xample.co.uk/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^files/example\.pdf$ / [L,R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^section\.php/11/1/life-drawing/?$ / [L,R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^section/116/1/drawings/?$ / [L,R=302,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Rewrite URLs for processing by router (section.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ article.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite URLs for processing by router (section.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ section.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valued reply. It works, but not for contact.php and page.php if I add them after section.php like below


# Rewrite URLs for processing by router (section.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ section.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite URLs for processing by router (page.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite URLs for processing by router (contact.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ contact.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

http://www.celiadickson.co.uk/

Comment: OK, what i'm wanting to do is get rid of the .php from all urls. The system generates pages on section.php. article.php. contact.php and page.php but cant use multiview as then the redirects don't work properly. these sorts of urls from a cms http://www.celiadickson.co.uk/section/2/1/wood-relief-carvings

Comment: Thanks, most pages work, section.php and now contact.php celiadickson.co.uk but page.php doesn't its on Biography link.

Comment: It works on section.php fine and the redirects work also. Thank you. But the same scenario (as section.php) on article.php and product.php is not working. Also can not log into the site admin on /admin

Comment: ok, so i can not add this under # Rewrite URLs for processing by router (article.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ article.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Is there anyway to include rules for article.php and product.php?

Comment: yes for articles and products there are names in the urls. These pages are all generated from the cms, same as sections eg celiadickson.co.uk/article/3/help-section

Comment: Thank you so so much. im so happy that is all working, ive been so stressed about it. Thank you sir. How can i make a contribution ?